# Python Count comma delimited list based on if row in other column equals x

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a data set of two columns where when columnA = 1 then in ColumnB I want to count the number of occurrences of x that is comma delimited

Sample data set that is within an excel file

```
columnA    columnB
1          x,a,b,c
2          d,e,g
3          a,r,x
4          y,x,o,a
```

What I've tried

```
if any ('1' in str(x) for x in excel_file['columnA']):
    count = excel_file['columnB'].astype(str).str.contains('x').value_counts()[True]
else:
    count = 0
```

This does get me the number of occurrences of x but it gets me all occurrences and not only when columnA is equal to 1 in the same row.

I know in excel it could be written as `countifs=(columnA, "1", columnB, "*x*")` but can't seem to find a similar way of doing this within python

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the expected output and a more *complete* example, there is only a single 1 in columnA

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for more completed sample data and expected outcome, I'd provide my preliminary answer:

Assuming this is how your data look:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c']], [2, ['d', 'e', 'g']], [3, ['a', 'r', 'x']], [4, ['y', 'x', 'o', 'a']]]
excel_file = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['columnA', 'columnB'])
```

Usually, I'd do your task with a for loop by row:

```
for idx, row in excel_file.iterrows():
    if row['columnA'] == 1:
        count = 0
        for item in row['columnB']:
            if item == 'x':
                count += 1
        print('Row', idx, 'has', count, 'occurrence(s) of x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was actually able to be solved pretty easily using len.

```
filter = excel_file[excel_file['columnA'].astype(str).str.contains('1')
filter_2 = len([filter[filter['columnB'].astype(str).str.contains('x')])
```

I had tried something similar earlier but I think separating it out into multiple functions rather than one was able to solve this pretty easily.

Thanks Yee for trying to provide an answer!